# How to develop Poker.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation, site-promotion

I know this is a subject which has been discussed a few times at various points in the past here, but as a relatively new user who would love to be active and helpful in this community, I would find it helpful to understand the views of other users on this subject.

This site has been running in beta for quite some time now (one of the longest lasting beta sites of those which have not yet been nuked or graduated to full sites), but we still have very low traffic and question volumes and *sometimes* quite poor quality content as well.

**What can/should we do about this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could we improve participation?](http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-could-we-improve-participation)